# 'int right' programing graphic c++

Tags: c++, redefinition

How can I fix the redefinition of `int right`? See code below.

This one here `int right=INT_MAX` is the problem

```
unsigned imagesize( int left, int top, int right, int bottom );
void getimage( int left, int top, int right, int bottom, void *bitmap );
void putimage( int left, int top, void *bitmap, int op );
void printimage(
    const char* title=NULL, 
    double width_inches=7, double border_left_inches=0.75, double border_top_inches=0.75,
    int left=0, int right=0, int right=INT_MAX, int bottom=INT_MAX,
    bool active=true, HWND hwnd=NULL
    );
```

Comment: Could you explain what's the problem with it? What have you tried, do you get any error, is there some behaviour you didn't expect?

Answer (score 2):

In your `printimage` declaration you have two input parameters called `right`:

```
    int left=0, int right=0, int right=INT_MAX, int bottom=INT_MAX,
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

You can't declare variables or parameters with the same name twice - how could you tell them apart to use them? Hence the redeclaration error. (I appreciate it doesn't matter too much in the declaration here, though: it only really matters that these are both ints, since you're just declaring the function signature, and the compiler could probably just ignore this as long as you got it right with different names in the function definition.)

Based on the pattern in your other declarations (left, top, right, bottom), I think you want to change the first one to be `int top`, i.e.

```
void printimage(
    const char* title=NULL, 
    double width_inches=7, double border_left_inches=0.75, double border_top_inches=0.75,
    int left=0, int top=0, int right=INT_MAX, int bottom=INT_MAX,
    bool active=true, HWND hwnd=NULL
    );
```